# What are these strange blades behind the N1 fan in a Boeing 747-8 engine?

Tags: boeing-747

It looks like a second fan or something. [image]

Comment: As a matter of phrasing, the fact that you aren't sure what something is doesn't make it strange. :) These are present on many (most) turbofan designs and have been for decades!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are Outlet Guide Vanes / Fan Exit Guide Vanes. They prevent the flow (bypass flow in this case) from rotating. The these vanes do not rotate, they are fixed to the housing. They also provide structural support.

Because there is no energy lost on the rotation of the flow the efficiency is increased.

Comment: Indeed they are present on the GE 787 engine also of course. http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-11-25/boeing-warns-of-ice-risks-for-ge-powered-787s-in-storms

Comment: Sorry I reviewed the pic it did actually have outlet guide vanes. My apology.

Comment: @Ethan no problem, I see you update your post, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Ethan: [How engines are assembled by Rolls Royce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfomloUg2Gw), a good documentary on the Trent 1000 with many details on what is inside the casing, and for sure many (good) questions :-)

Comment: @mins The GE and Rolls Royce engines are almost exactly alike on the 787, have the chevrons on the end, both have outlet guide lines, and also similar thrust. Its pretty weird. I will make sure to watch the documentary also.

Comment: @Ethan: [This is the part you are talking about](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TnFcR.jpg), being welded. In this video. Enjoy!

Comment: @mins I'm just saying the engines are almost alike. I don't want to get a warning again, so this will be my last comment.

Comment: The exit vanes also extract a little amount of thrust from the flow by converting some of the rotational energy into a forward force on the vanes.

Comment: @PeterKämpf That is indeed how the recuperated energy manifests itself.